# How to compile this program? error at linker stage

Tags: windows, gcc, linker, ada, libc

I have installed gnat gpl 2016 on windows 10 and try to compile following (small) program with gnatmake. Problem is that due import of one function from libc the task seems to be far more complicated than simple gnatmake.exe gsh_repl.adb [gnatmake would compile this on linux just fine - in worst case scenario adding -lglibc would suffice]. My problem is that I have no idea which option I should add to make linking stage complete succesfully. Here is program:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with System;
procedure GSH_Repl is

  function System (Command : in String) return Integer is
    Actual_Cmd : aliased constant String := Command & Character'Val (0); -- append nul to string
    function System_C (Command : in Standard.System.Address) return Integer
    with Import => True, External_Name => "system", Convention => StdCall;
  begin
    return System_C (Actual_Cmd'Address);
  end System;

begin
  loop
    declare
      File : Ada.Text_Io.File_Type;
      Line : constant String := Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
      Status : Integer := 0;
    begin
      if Line = "exit" then
    exit;
      end if;

      Ada.Text_Io.Open (File, Ada.Text_Io.Out_File, "script");
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (File, Line);
      Ada.Text_Io.Close (File);

      Status := System ("c:\repos\gsh\obj\dev\gsh.exe script");
      Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line ("$? = " & Integer'Image (Status));
    end;
  end loop;
end GSH_Repl;
```

There may be some kind of bug in the program - but it compiles fine and fails at linker stage:

```
>gnatmake.exe -L"c:\Programs\GNAT_2016\bin" -llibglibc-2.0-0.dll gsh_repl.adb
gnatmake.exe -L"c:\Programs\GNAT_2016\bin" -llibglibc-2.0-0.dll gsh_repl.adb
gnatbind -x gsh_repl.ali
gnatlink gsh_repl.ali -Lc:\Programs\GNAT_2016\bin
.\gsh_repl.o:gsh_repl.adb:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `system@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling C:\Programs\GNAT_2016\bin\gcc.exe
gnatmake: *** link failed.
```

Comment: `undefined reference to system@4` suggests there's some sort of name mangling going on ... a first step might be to find the function names in the library ... or is it in libc rather than glibc?

Comment: If you scroll down a bit from [here](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/platform_specific_information.html#mixed-language-programming-on-windows) you’ll find stuff about calling conventions. The `@4` is added because of the `StdCall` convention; you could try the `C` convention instead. Or you could try one of the `GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn` calls, perhaps?

Comment: @SimonWright Really, calling convention was the issue :/
Thx for help - didn't even occur to me that this might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stdcall is the convention used by win32 APIs. When you're compiling your code with GNAT, the libc is GCC's libc, so it uses the C convention for everything.

Altering the System_C binding to the following:

```
function System_C (Command : in Standard.System.Address) return Integer
with Import => True, External_Name => "system", Convention => C;
```

Will fix your problem.